# Folder structure with REST in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

It's possible to create a **REST API** in PHP to create a folder structure in the server? what i need is to recieve two parameters **ID** and **DataID** where **ID** is going to be the parent folder and **DataID** suposed to be de child folder, i'am new with REST and API's, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd recommend using a framework and storing `ID,DataID,Path`,etc. in a database

Comment: Stop thinking in folders. The urls should point to a resource and a resource could be anything you want really. That said. What are you serving?

Comment: Ok, for now i'm not serving anything becouse the only thing requested is to generate the folder structure but i dont know what kind of data i can serve back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use a framework for this, as it makes things a lot easier for you. It also provides you with a basic infrastructure (even some kind of folder structure if you want) and other best practices.

Take a look at the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) which is a php micro framework that will help you to quickly write simple web applications and APIs. It provides you with all the basic features you'll need to develop a RESTful API (i.e. routing, templating).

I also made a little [sample application](https://github.com/KlickReform/weblab/tree/master/rest/slim-framework) using the Slim Framework some time ago. This may help you get started.

Comment: Definitely 'slim' looks good to work with RESTful API, i will take a look in this. thanks.

Comment: I hope it will help you. If you have any questions regarding Slim I will be happy to help. If you find it useful you may also accept my answer for this question. Regards.